# Ubuntu: no root file system is defined + freezing

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, usb, usb-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my Acer Nitro an515-53 and when I click install now  it says no root file system defined.

Also, when I try to click the +, -, or the "change" button it freezes and go unresponsive.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Recreate the installer and check the validity of the download and the installed installer. [See](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) on the checksum.

A / partition is mandatory (ie. the message) but the installer crashing to me means you have a faulty installer.

Answer (score 0):

I just designated the / (root) partition during the install. It will not install if you don't designate an install point. Hope this helps!